# Speed up solving a triangular linear system with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I have a square matrix S (160 x 160), and a huge matrix X (160 x 250000).  Both are dense numpy arrays.

My goal: find Q such that  Q  = inv(chol(S)) * X, where chol(S) is the lower cholesky factorization of S.

Naturally, a simple solution is

```
cholS = scipy.linalg.cholesky( S, lower=True)
scipy.linalg.solve( cholS, X )
```

My problem: this solution is *noticeably* slower (>2x) in python than when I try the same in Matlab. Here are some timing experiments:

```
timeit np.linalg.solve( cholS, X)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.63 s per loop

timeit scipy.linalg.solve_triangular( cholS, X, lower=True)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.19 s per loop

timeit scipy.linalg.solve( cholS, X)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.81 s per loop

[matlab]
cholS \ X
0.675 s

[matlab using only one thread via -singleCompThread]
cholS \ X
1.26 s
```

Basically, I'd like to know: (1) can I reach Matlab-like speeds in python? and (2) why is the scipy version so slow?

The solver should be able to take advantage of the fact that chol(S) is triangular.  However, using numpy.linalg.solve() is faster than scipy.linalg.solve_triangular(), even though the numpy call doesn't use the triangular structure at all.  What gives?  The matlab solver seems to auto-detect when my matrix is triangular, but python cannot.

I'd be happy to use a custom call to BLAS/LAPACK routines for solving triangular linear systems, but I really don't want to write that code myself.

For reference, I'm using scipy version 11.0 and the Enthought python distribution (which uses Intel's MKL library for vectorization), so I *think* I should be able to reach Matlab-like speeds.

Answer (score 20):

TL;DR: Don't use numpy's or scipy's `solve` when you have a triangular system, just use `scipy.linalg.solve_triangular` with at least the `check_finite=False` keyword argument for fast and non-destructive solutions.

---

I found this thread after stumbling across some discrepancies between `numpy.linalg.solve` and `scipy.linalg.solve` (and `scipy's lu_solve`, etc.). I don't have Enthought's MKL-based Numpy/Scipy, but I hope my findings can help you in some way.

With the pre-built binaries for Numpy and Scipy (32-bit, running on Windows 7):

1. I see a significant difference between `numpy.linalg.solve` and `scipy.linalg.solve` when solving for a vector `X` (i.e., `X` is 160 by 1). Scipy runtime is 1.23x numpy's, which is I think substantial.
2. However, most of the difference appears to be due to scipy's `solve` checking for invalid entries. When passing `check_finite=False` into scipy.linalg.solve, scipy's `solve` runtime is 1.02x numpy's.
3. Scipy's solve using destructive updates, i.e., with `overwrite_a=True, overwrite_b=True` is slightly faster than numpy's solve (which is non-destructive). Numpy's solve runtime is 1.021x destructive scipy.linalg.solve. Scipy with just `check_finite=False` has runtime 1.04x the destructive case. In summary, destructive `scipy.linalg.solve` is very slightly faster than either of these cases.
4. The above are for a vector `X`. If I make `X` a wide array, specifically 160 by 10000, `scipy.linalg.solve` with `check_finite=False` is essentially as fast as with `check_finite=False, overwrite_a=True, overwrite_b=True`. Scipy's `solve` (without any special keywords) runtime is 1.09x this "unsafe" (`check_finite=False`) call. Numpy's `solve` has runtime 1.03x scipy's fastest for this array `X` case.
5. `scipy.linalg.solve_triangular` delivers significant speedups in both these cases, but you have to turn off input checking, i.e., pass in `check_finite=False`. The runtime for the fastest solve was 5.68x and 1.76x `solve_triangular`'s, for vector and array `X`, respectively, with `check_finite=False`.
6. `solve_triangular` with destructive computation (`overwrite_b=True`) gives you no speedup on top of `check_finite=False` (and actually hurts slightly for the array `X` case).
7. I, ignoramus, was previously unaware of `solve_triangular` and was using `scipy.linalg.lu_solve` as a triangular solver, i.e., instead of `solve_triangular(cholS, X)` doing `lu_solve((cholS, numpy.arange(160)), X)` (both produce the same answer). But I discovered that `lu_solve` used in this way has runtime 1.07x unsafe `solve_triangular` for the vector `X` case, while its runtime was 1.76x for the array `X` case. I'm not sure why `lu_solve` is so much slower for array `X`, compared to vector `X`, but the lesson is to use `solve_triangular` (without infinite checks).
8. Copying the data to Fortran format didn't seem to matter at all. Neither does converting to `numpy.matrix`.

I might as well compare my non-MKL Python libraries against single-threaded (`maxNumCompThreads=1`) Matlab 2013a. The fastest Python implementations above had 4.5x longer runtime for the vector `X` case and 6.3x longer runtime for the fat matrix `X` case.

However, here's the Python script I used to benchmark these, perhaps someone with MKL-accelerated Numpy/Scipy can post their numbers. Note that I just comment out the line `n = 10000` to disable the fat matrix `X` case and do the `n=1` vector case. (Sorry.)

```
import scipy.linalg as sla
import numpy.linalg as nla
from numpy.random import RandomState
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np

RNG = RandomState(69)

m=160
n=1
#n=10000
Ac = RNG.randn(m,m)
if 1:
    Ac = np.triu(Ac)

bc = RNG.randn(m,n)
Af = Ac.copy("F")
bf = bc.copy("F")

if 0: # Save to Matlab format
    import scipy.io as io
    io.savemat("b_%d.mat"%(n,), dict(A=Ac, b=bc))
    import sys
    sys.exit(0)

def lapper(fn, source, **kwargs):
    Alocal = source[0].copy()
    blocal = source[1].copy()
    fn(Alocal, blocal,**kwargs)

laps = (1000 if n<=1 else 100)
def printer(t, s=''):
    print ("%g seconds, %d laps, " % (t/float(laps), laps)) + s
    return t/float(laps)

t=[]
print "C"
t.append(printer(timeit(lambda: lapper(sla.solve, (Ac,bc)), number=laps),
                 "scipy.solve"))
t.append(printer(timeit(lambda: lapper(sla.solve, (Ac,bc), check_finite=False),
                        number=laps), "scipy.solve, infinite-ok"))
t.append(printer(timeit(lambda: lapper(nla.solve, (Ac,bc)), number=laps),
                 "numpy.solve"))

#print "F" # Doesn't seem to matter
#printer(timeit(lambda: lapper(sla.solve, (Af,bf)), number=laps))
#printer(timeit(lambda: lapper(nla.solve, (Af,bf)), number=laps))

print "sla with tweaks"
t.append(printer(timeit(lambda: lapper(sla.solve, (Ac,bc), overwrite_a=True,
                              overwrite_b=True,  check_finite=False),
                        number=laps), "scipy.solve destructive"))

print "Tri"
t.append(printer(timeit(lambda: lapper(sla.solve_triangular, (Ac,bc)),
                        number=laps), "scipy.solve_triangular"))
t.append(printer(timeit(lambda: lapper(sla.solve_triangular, (Ac,bc),
                              check_finite=False), number=laps),
                 "scipy.solve_triangular, inf-ok"))
t.append(printer(timeit(lambda: lapper(sla.solve_triangular, (Ac,bc),
                                       overwrite_b=True, check_finite=False),
                        number=laps), "scipy.solve_triangular destructive"))

print "LU"
piv = np.arange(m)
t.append(printer(timeit(lambda: lapper(
    lambda X,b: sla.lu_solve((X, piv),b,check_finite=False),
    (Ac,bc)), number=laps), "LU"))

print "all times:"
print t
```

Output of the above script for the vector case, `n=1`:

```
C
0.000739405 seconds, 1000 laps, scipy.solve
0.000624746 seconds, 1000 laps, scipy.solve, infinite-ok
0.000590003 seconds, 1000 laps, numpy.solve
sla with tweaks
0.000608365 seconds, 1000 laps, scipy.solve destructive
Tri
0.000208711 seconds, 1000 laps, scipy.solve_triangular
9.38371e-05 seconds, 1000 laps, scipy.solve_triangular, inf-ok
9.37682e-05 seconds, 1000 laps, scipy.solve_triangular destructive
LU
0.000100215 seconds, 1000 laps, LU
all times:
[0.0007394047886284343, 0.00062474593940593, 0.0005900030818282472, 0.0006083650710913095, 0.00020871054023307778, 9.383710445114923e-05, 9.37682389063692e-05, 0.00010021534750467032]
```

Output of the above script for the matrix case `n=10000`:

```
C
0.118985 seconds, 100 laps, scipy.solve
0.113687 seconds, 100 laps, scipy.solve, infinite-ok
0.115569 seconds, 100 laps, numpy.solve
sla with tweaks
0.113122 seconds, 100 laps, scipy.solve destructive
Tri
0.0725959 seconds, 100 laps, scipy.solve_triangular
0.0634396 seconds, 100 laps, scipy.solve_triangular, inf-ok
0.0638423 seconds, 100 laps, scipy.solve_triangular destructive
LU
0.1115 seconds, 100 laps, LU
all times:
[0.11898513112988955, 0.11368747217793944, 0.11556863916356903, 0.11312182352918797, 0.07259593807427585, 0.0634396208970783, 0.06384230931663318, 0.11150022257648459]
```

Note that the above Python script can save its arrays as Matlab .MAT data files. This is currently disabled (`if 0`, sorry), but if enabled, you can test Matlab's speed on the exact same data. Here's a timing script for Matlab:

```
clear
q = load('b_10000.mat');
A=q.A;
b=q.b;
clear q
matrix_time = timeit(@() A\b)

q = load('b_1.mat');
A=q.A;
b=q.b;
clear q
vector_time = timeit(@() A\b)
```

You'll need the `timeit` function from Mathworks File Exchange: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function. This produces the following output:

```
matrix_time =
    0.0099989
vector_time =
   2.2487e-05
```

The upshot of this empirical analysis is, in Python at least, don't use numpy's or scipy's `solve` when you have a triangular system, just use `scipy.linalg.solve_triangular` with at least the `check_finite=False` keyword argument for fast and non-destructive solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the equation: `Q = inv(chol(S)) * X`, here is my test:

```
import scipy.linalg
import numpy as np

N = 160
M = 100000
S = np.random.randn(N, N)
B = np.random.randn(N, M)
S = np.dot(S, S.T)

cS = scipy.linalg.cholesky(S, lower=True)
Y1 = scipy.linalg.solve(cS, B)
icS = scipy.linalg.inv(cS)
Y2 = np.dot(icS, B)

np.allclose(Y1, Y2)
```

output:

```
True
```

Here is the time test:

```
%time scipy.linalg.solve(cholS, B)
%time np.linalg.solve(cholS, B)
%time scipy.linalg.solve_triangular(cholS, B, lower=True)
%time ics=scipy.linalg.inv(cS);np.dot(ics, B)
```

output:

```
CPU times: user 2.07 s, sys: 0.00 s, total: 2.07 s
Wall time: 2.08 s
CPU times: user 1.93 s, sys: 0.00 s, total: 1.93 s
Wall time: 1.92 s
CPU times: user 1.12 s, sys: 0.00 s, total: 1.12 s
Wall time: 1.13 s
CPU times: user 0.71 s, sys: 0.00 s, total: 0.71 s
Wall time: 0.72 s
```

I don't know why `scipy.linalg.solve_triangular` is slower than `numpy.linalg.solve` on your system, but the `inv` version is the fastest.

Comment: From [_Numerical Recipes: The Art of Scientific Computing_, page 41 of the latest edition](http://www.nr.com/oldverswitcher.html) "If we are getting the matrix inverse anyway, can’t we later let it multiply a new right-hand side to get an additional solution? This does work, but it gives an answer that is very susceptible to round-off error and not nearly as good as if the new vector had been included with the set of right-hand side vectors in the first instance."

Comment: @Jaime In fact its [accuracy](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.6035v1.pdf) is not as bad as usually thought, but that still doesn't make it a good way to solve any linear system. "Several widely-used textbooks lead the reader to believe that solving a linear system of equations Ax = b by multiplying b by a computed inverse inv(A) is inaccurate. [...] In fact, under reasonable assumptions on how the inverse is computed, x=inv(A)*b is as accurate as the solution computed by the best backward-stable solvers."

Comment: I can confirm that using the explicit inverse does seem to be at least 2x faster than calling "solve".  I hadn't even tried this solution due to the enduring folk wisdom that using the explicit inverse is vulnerable to inaccuracy.  I'll go try this out and see if there are noticeable accuracy issues.  Thanks.

Comment: @jorgeca Of course the result is going to be the same "under reasonable assumptions." The problem is knowing if your system fulfills those "reasonable assumptions." Without a prior test, or a theoretical justification, I don't think it is a good idea to go down that path to save 1s. of computer time.

Comment: @Jaime I only pointed out that the error bound on the inverse is tighter than usually thought, while saying that it's not a good idea in general. A situation where using the inverse might be preferred is described in the 3rd reference of the paper I linked before. It is not the case described in this question. Back to it, I suspect too much time is being spent inside [`asarray_chkfinite`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/48) or somehow scipy is not using MKL.

Comment: @jorgeca's linked paper is very interesting. It says that solving Ax=b as inv(A)*b is as stable & accurate as "better" methods (LU, etc.) if b isn't "bad", i.e., if it isn't (nearly) orthogonal to "small singular subspace" (span of left singular vectors with small singular values). And even if b *is* "bad", it'll still be *accurate* (inv(A)*b is as close to the real solution as A\b) but not stable (A*(inv(A)*b) will be much farther away from b than A*(A\b)). SO, if you just want a solution, inv(A)*b will be accurate (and usually stable).

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things to try:

- `X = X.copy('F')`  # use fortran-order arrays, so that a copy is avoided
- `Y = solve_triangular(cholS, X, overwrite_b=True)` # avoid another copy, but trash contents of `X`
- `Y = solve_triangular(cholS, X, check_finite=False)` # Scipy >= 0.12 only --- but doesn't seem to have a large effect on speed...

With both of these, it should be pretty much equivalent to a direct call to MKL with no buffer copies.

I can't reproduce the issue with `np.linalg.solve` and `scipy.linalg.solve` having different speeds --- with the BLAS + LAPACK combination I have, both seem the same speed.